# Delete ACF Field from the backend with expired date

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF field called sub seminars, inside this is another field called sub seminars which is a repeater field containing start_date and end_date.

I have posts that have several rows of this field.

I want to delete the row of the repeater field which has an expired date in it from the backend so that it doesn't show up in the front end.

I am using this function to achieve this but somethings are not working.

```
add_filter('acf/load_value/name=repeater_field_name', 'delete_old_courses_by_date');
function delete_old_courses_by_date($rows, $post_id, $field) {
  if (!is_array($value) || !count($value)) {
    return $value;
  }
  // get the current timestamp
  $now = time();

  // set up a new array to hold the values we keep
  $new_value = array();
  foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // the php strtotime() function could fail depending on
    // the return format of the date/time fields
    // this requires a valid date/time format as documented here
    // http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php
    // if this does not work I probably won't be much help figuring
    // our how to covert your return value to something usable
    $start = strtotime($row['start_date']);
    $end = strtotime($row['end_date']);
    if ($start > $now || $end > $now) {
      $new_value[] = $row;
    }
  }
  return $new_value;
}
```

If I put repeater_field_name as start_date, all the start_date rows are deleted.

Please not my date format is Ymd and I don't know if the format is compatible with strtotime() function

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is there no one who knows this stuff ?

Comment: how does it look, if you check the data in the values? 
var_dump($now. " must be bestween " .$start. " and ".$end);
is it the same format?

Comment: They are in the same format. The start_date and End_date are both in the format of Ymd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me

```
<?php   for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
        $ap = get_post_meta($post->ID,'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_start_date',true);
        $startdate = date("Ymd", strtotime($ap));
        $todaydate = date("Ymd");
      if(strtotime($todaydate) > strtotime($startdate) && !empty($ap)){
       $del_data = array(
                    'Ref' => 'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_ref',
                    'Start date' => 'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_start_date',
                    'End Date' => 'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_end_date',
                    'Venue' => 'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_venue',
                    'Fees' => 'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_fees',
                    'CPE Credits' => 'sub_seminars_'.$i.'_cpe_credits'
        );
      delete_row('sub_seminars', 1);
    }
   } ?>
```

Hope this helps to someone else.